# Est-il correct d'omettre la cédille de "ça" quand le ç est majuscule ?

Tags: orthographe, diacritiques, majuscules

Il n'est pas possible d'atteindre facilement un `ç` majuscule avec un clavier d'ordinateur (c'est certes possible, en rentrant le code octal ou avec la table de caractères, mais c'est fastidieux).

Étant donné que le mot *ça* est le seul mot de la langue française commençant avec un c cédille, le plus simple et d'omettre le cédille. Par exemple :

> Ca va bien ?

Est-ce que c'est admis ou non ?

Comment: Une cédille n’est pas un accent. Du coup, je ne sui pas convaincu par la clôture, en tout cas pas sans édition de la question *et* de la plupart des réponses, ce qui me semble un peu excessif.

Comment: @Édouard: Si on suit les liens de la question dupliquée, on lit "... en français, l’accent a pleine valeur orthographique. [...] **Il en va de même pour le tréma et la cédille.**" Il me semble que ça répond à la question.

Comment: Plusieurs des réponses proposées là-bas répondent à cette question-ci. Les questions demeurent cependant différentes.

Comment: La grosse différence entre les accents et le cédille est que le `ç` majuscule est réellement inaccessible avec le clavier. Les accents et les trémas le sont, bien qu'ils requièrent deux touches pour les moins courants, mais c'est toujours mieux que d'aller dans la table de caractères.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D'après [l'académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue#5_strong-em-accentuation-des-majuscules-em-strong), il faudrait mettre une majuscule. Après, dans les faits, ce n'est pas toujours le cas et c'est même une tendance étant donné, comme tu l'as si bien dit, les difficultés à saisir ces caractères au clavier.

Comment: -1 pour "il faudrait" au lieu de "il faut". Même si cette faute est courante, ne pas mettre de cédille à la capitale Ç est incorrect . Une limitation de Windows ne doit pas influer sur les règles d'écriture du français.

Comment: @jlliagre Est-il possible d'atteindre le ç majuscule facilement avec linux ?

Comment: Ça dépend des distributions et surtout de la configuration de clavier choisies. Sous Linux Mint, en mode console ou en mode graphique avec le clavier "French alternative", je l'obtiens avec `AltGr+Maj.+ç`. Sous OS X, c'est `Alt+ç`.